# What's the term for flickering eye movement

Tags: terminology, loanwords

If you're looking out of the window of a moving train and at things as they go by (rather than a single object that you're leaving behind), your eyes appear to be flickering. There's a specific term for this.. which I can't remember!

Comment: It's more like a blur than a flicker, isn't it? Don't your eyes just blink from staring so hard? ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Saccades, I believe. You can also have 'micro-saccades' which are what the eye does to maintain a constant image; you'd be blind otherwise.

Comment: The whole subject of the eye is fascinating. You know how when you notice a bad smell, after a while it fades away? That's because of a thing called neuron fatigue. The neurons detecting the smell register *change*, so if something stays the same they stop firing. It's the same with vision. If your eyes didn't constantly move (micro-saccades), the neurons would stop registering and you'd go blind. They've tested it by paralysing the eye muscles.

Comment: Saccades are important for understanding scanpaths in eye-tracking studies, a technique widely used in human-computer interaction research and increasingly in commercial user experience evaluations (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_tracking#History)